# Twitter Bootstrap & ZeroClipboard.swf (missing file error)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, zeroclipboard

I used **Twitter Bootstrap** (latest version, *v3.2.0*) to set up a single-page basic website.  All functionality seems fine, but my JavaScript Console, upon loading the site, indicates the following error:

```
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"
```

It points to a *missing file*, namely "../assets/flash/**ZeroClipboard.swf**".

I cannot find much information on how ZeroClipboard is integrated into Twitter Bootstrap.  **Has someone had a similar error?**

Should I download the file to avoid the error even if 1) it doesn't seem to be causing problems and 2) I don't know where the error is originating from?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

ZeroClipboard is only used in Bootstrap's documentation to make the "Copy" buttons for the code samples work. Presumably you're including `docs.min.js` (or some other docs-specific JS) by mistake.

Comment: Beautiful!  Thanks so much for catching that -- I have removed docs.min.js and all is right with the world!